# Another UIButton background color issue

Tags: ios, uibutton

Yet another simple issue with changing the background color of a UIButton. So I have figured after searching a bit that a common way is to either create an image or subview.

I have created a button in storyboard and connected it to an outlet. In my VC class I have the following

### .h

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *uiLoginButton;
```

### .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"%s and frame rect %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self.uiLoginButton); //here uiloginbutton does not have any size!

CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100.0, 100.0);

self.uiLoginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.uiLoginButton.frame = buttonRect;
self.uiLoginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NSLog(@"%s and frame rect %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self.uiLoginButton);    
}
```

No I have set the values in CGRectMake randomly because the IBOutlet button's frame is 0. How come?

What is the correct way to actually change the button's color?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are creating a button in nib you can change all the properties via nib itself.
Like this
[image]

OR

If you want to do it codewise since you are adding it via nib points to note

- No need for an initialization.since it is a property from IB.
- Just directly provide frame via IB or in code via `-setFrame:` method
- To set color, you can use `-setBackgroundcolor:` method

So my .h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *uiLoginButton;
```

.m

```
[self.uiLoginButton setFrame:buttonRect];
[self.uiLoginButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have to use setFrame though and setting Custom in nib is required, otherwise (with RoundedRect) only the corners are coloured and the button remains white.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test all method in referent to understand: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

If you draw UIButton in storyBoard,NSLog frame in viewDidAppear.

If you use RounRect type and want to change color, use storyBoard, don't use code.

IF you use Custom type, use Image Background, not set color:

[button setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: I tried to set UIImage with color but didn't know how. Would have been good if you provided an example. Furthermore, for custom type setBackgroundColor: is sufficient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461309/how-to-auto-draw-an-uiimage-with-frame-and-color/15461339?noredirect=1#15461339

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding the value of `self.uiLoginButton`

remove these lines

```
CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100.0, 100.0);

self.uiLoginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.uiLoginButton.frame = buttonRect;
```