# How to auto draw an UIImage with frame and color?

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image

I try something to create an UIImage with a frame and color but don't know what the correct way.

```
UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor]]];
```

Is the above line correct? How to create image size? Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make a `UIImage` category.

such as `UIImage(Color)`

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);

    [color set];
    UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [path fill];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

**How to use :**

```
#import "UIImage + Color"

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor] andSize:yourSize];
```